# Error! You've attempted to require '@react-native-firebase/auth' version '6.2.0', however

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

Error! You've attempted to require `@react-native-firebase/auth` version '6.2.0', however, the `@react-native-firebase/app` module is of a different version (6.3.4).

I get this error whenever I launch the app. I've tried to reinstall all the modules, to delete and reinstall, to install all react native firebase modules to version 6.3.4, to version 6.2.0 but still nothing.
I can't use the firebase package because I've implemented firebase differently.
Do you have any idea what should I do?

Package.json:

```
  "name": "Vanto",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.2.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^6.2.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^6.2.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.17",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.60.31",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.5",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-admob": "^2.0.0-beta.6",
    "react-native-appearance": "^0.3.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.3",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-ionicons": "^4.6.4",
    "react-native-navigation-bar-color": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-restart": "0.0.14",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-typescript-transformer": "^1.2.13",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.6.2",
    "styled-components": "^5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5",
    "uninstall": "0.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your package.json? And does that happen on android and ios?

Comment: added package.json, i only build for android

Comment: from what it seems, you are missing the react-native-firebase package

Comment: using @react-native-firebase; in the oficial docs they say to first yarn add @react-native-firebase/app, that is the package itself

Comment: auth and storage are just completions, but the main package is the app one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by cleaning node cache and yarn cache as well as reinstalling react native firebase modules all in 6.2.0